# Can I make a jQuery JSONP request without adding the '?callback=' parameter in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

The server won't accept any parameters in a request URL, so I need to remove all the extra parameters in the URL and of course I can't control the server.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://cross-domain.com/the_jsonp_file,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: 'true',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    },
});
```

The JSONP file:

```
jsonCallback({"test": "hello"});
```

When I send that Ajax request, the URL looks like this:

```
http://cross-domain.com/the_jsonp_file?callback=jsonCallback
```

But I need this (without parameters):

```
http://cross-domain.com/the_jsonp_file
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my whole situation:

```
function MyClass(imgs) {
    // imgs is array of URLs
    this.imgs = imgs;

    this.submit = function() {
        // button click event triggers this method
        this._show();
    };

    this._show = function() {
        var _this = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < _this.imgs.length; i++) {
            (function($, j) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: _this.imgs[j],
                    jsonp : false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                    cache: 'true',
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    success: function(json) {
                      console.log(_this.imgs[j]);
                    },
                });
            })(jQuery, i);
        };
    };
};
```

And I got this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jsonCallback' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

Weird thing is few requests are successfully calling jsonCallback.

Comment: The server refuses requests with query strings altogether?

Comment: You might be best just to write the JSONP code yourself, rather than using jQuery...

Comment: I tried `dataType: 'script'` in ajax setting and It's making URL without any parameters but I have no idea how to make the callback function working.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to do JSONP without specifying the callback. It's a script tag, the only way to pass the name of the callback is through the URL. What am I missing? Maybe it wraps it in a default callback? What's the URL?

Answer (score 11):

Check the jQuery docs - they say to say jsonp: false and jsonpCallback : 'callbackFunction' in the ajax args....like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://cross-domain.com/the_jsonp_file',
    jsonp : false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    // contentType: 'application/json', -- you can't set content type for a <script> tag, this option does nothing for jsonp | KevinB
    cache: 'true',
    dataType : 'jsonp'
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. it seems working but I got this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jsonCallback' of object [object Window] is not a function`. tho few elements are successfully calls the callback function.

Comment: @Jonypoins Are you using jQuery 1.5+?

Comment: That's because you haven't defined a function named jsonCallback. The value of the jsonpCallback property needs to be a globally available function to be executed when the response is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Every requests calls the same callback `jsonCallback`, so I thought that's the problem.

First, Javascript in document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Gallery([
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '27b2afa5c77c2510'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '13df51b2f2801bc1'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '4de326fc9a2c5a24'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '60c266a73ba699bc'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '3db01e95aaf2b9f2'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '94eb17f9b0e1be9c'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', 'ca8c5c3c0b8cd5ae'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '6b0f5c5737ee88fd'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', '318d8ebb51a97a15'],
        ['http://cross-domain.url/whatever', 'f5028c8b62e81a8b'],
    ]);
</script>
```

Client uploads JSONP file(just another Javascript file) to the server like this:

```
jsonCallback_27b2afa5c77c2510({"test": "hello"});
```

**Added random hex string after `jsonCallback_` to separate each requests like jQuery's default callback does.**

Read random hex string from input and set as `jsonpCallback`:

```
function Gallery(imgs) {
    // imgs is array of URLs
    this.imgs = imgs;

    this.submit = function() {
        // button click event triggers this method
        this._show();
    };

    this._show = function() {
        var _this = this;

        for (var i = 0; i < _this.imgs.length; i++) {
            (function($, j) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: _this.imgs[j][0],
                    jsonp : false,
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback_' + _this.imgs[j][1],
                    cache: 'true',
                    dataType:'jsonp',
                    success: function(json) {
                      // Process
                      console.log(json.test);
                    },
                });
            })(jQuery, i);
        };
    };
};
```

Thank you @Adam @Kevin B @Dcullen and everyone! :D

p.s: I typed every sources above only for example, it may not correct.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP requires a callback as part of the URL.  I would guess based on the description that the server you are accessing does not support JSONP.

jQuery adds a script tag to your document, which when added runs the API request, the response calls the callback function in your code (this is simplifying it).

You can take a look at Wikipedia if you want a more accurate description.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works

Comment: Yes, the server does not support JSONP but I want to use resources from the server using JSONP.

Comment: Unfortunately you the server has to support JSONP in order for it to work.  Otherwise you get the script error mentioned above.  You have 2 other options: 1. Setting up a proxy. 2. CORS (this requires server configuration also)

Comment: "Every requests calls the same callback jsonCallback, so I thought that's the problem." - this was my problem. thanks. +1