# Omit Callback string in JsonP Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, parameters, proxy, callback, jsonp

**How can omit the parameter callback in the url generated with sencha touch using JsonP?**

For example

Url Generated

```
http://api.example.com/get_players?callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1
```

Url I Want

```
http://api.example.com/get_players
```

I could removed the others parameter like page, limit start int the url using this configuration in the config proxy:

```
proxy: {
   type: 'jsonp',

   pageParam: false, //to remove param "page"
   startParam: false, //to remove param "start"
   limitParam: false, //to remove param "limit"
   noCache: false, //to remove param "_dc"

   url:  http://api.example.com/get_players,
}
```

Can i use a callback method without the string callback in the url? Thanks!!!

### SOLUTION

I had to use and intermediate service because the API does not work with jsonp. JSONP allways include the callback string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need a callback for jsonp

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864096/can-i-make-a-jquery-jsonp-request-without-adding-the-callback-parameter-in-u)

Comment: The problem is that the api I'm using is validating the parameters and does not allow the callback parameter. So you can not use sencha touch with a api that valde parameters?