# ajax error: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/json:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get data from a server using `JSONP` but I keep getting a warning in my console

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/json:
```

Below is my ajax call

```
var loginData = {
    "strUniqueID" : "123",
    "UserName" : "UserName",
    "Password" : "Password"
};

$.ajax({
    url: http://domain.com,
    type: "POST",
    data: {'data':$.toJSON(loginData)},
    contentType: "text/plain",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Display the error.
        console.log('Error: ' + textStatus);
        console.log('Error thrown: ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Because of the warning I am receiving I am also getting this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

In Firefox this shows up as

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Is this because my data isn't getting brought back in the correct format?

If I open the URL with the parameters I get the response correctly

```
{"response":"SESSION ID"}
```

But I also get an error from the ajax call

```
Error: parsererror
Error thrown: jsonCallback was not called
```

I've been racking my brains with this for a few hours now and I am stumped!

Comment: Do you actually have a function in your page called `jsonCallback`? If not, then that's one problem. You either don't specify it and let jQuery create one for you, or you do specify it but you have to actually create it exactly with the same name. Judging by the response you get, it doesn't seem like you need to specify one. I would remove that parameter completely from the request.

Comment: No I don't, I don't understand if I need it or not. What would I do when I call that function?

Comment: Nothing. You have a success handler already defined. jQuery will redirect it to the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found another **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864096/can-i-make-a-jquery-jsonp-request-without-adding-the-callback-parameter-in-u#answer-12864429)** which helped me.

I needed to allow JSONP request on the service to send back the correct response

Comment: I am surprised that you didn't see the error before. You should have seen `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://yoursite.com' is therefore not allowed access.` That would have been an indication that you had to enable CORS in the first place.

Comment: I switched to JSONP a while back and totally forgot about it. I have tried so many combinations, i'm just happy its finally working